# Difference between vision and prophecy

Tags: meaning, etymology

Is there a difference between the meaning of the words prophecy and vision? could they be the same thing? If not what is their difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Vision**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vision)

> Something that you imagine : a picture that you see in your mind

[**Prophecy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prophecy)

> A statement that something will happen in the future

A vision necessarily implies a 'visual' be it hallucinatory, imagined, etc. experience, which doesn't necessarily include a prediction of any kind nor need it even be about the future (for instance you can have a vision of the past), whereas a prophecy is specifically a prediction about the future, which is to say the *message* behind a *vision* of the future

Surely there is considerable overlap, and colloquially **vision** is often used as a synonym for **prophecy**, but strictly speaking that is incorrect

Comment: so in the case that someone forsees the future that would be supposed to be a vision or a prophecy?

Comment: Seeing the future would be the *vision*, communicating the events which occur in the *vision* would be the **prophecy**

Comment: Your good answer (+1) seems to cover this too, but I think an even better (apples to apples/oranges to oranges) question for the OP to ask would perhaps be one about the difference between “a visionary” (the noun) and “a prophet.” I see more potential overlap of/confusion with “**being** a visionary” and “**being** a prophet” than with “**having** a vision” and “**making** a prophecy.” cc:@hedgehog

Comment: @hedgehog in the case that someone foresees the future, they would be said to have had a 'prophetic.

Comment: @PapaPoule as for the example you provided,  i can say that the visionary and the prophet do not connect, as to a visionary is a person who sees in front, for new plans new things etc, its the guy that dreams of stuff and want to make them happen, it is a different thing from what we are discussing here

Comment: @Spagirl you say he would have a propethic, what is the difference of that  with the prophecy.

Comment: @hedgehog I don't know what happened there: when I typed my comment it said 'they would be said to have had a 'prophetic vision'.

Comment: @Spagirl oh ok, so still a prophetic vision could be thought of as an actual prophecy? does the etymologies connect?